# Can't register Cordova App for push notifications using Azure

Tags: android, cordova, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to set up push notifications (just Android for now) with Azure Mobile Services.

I have:

**Cordova 6.2.0**

- phonegap-push-plugin
- cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps

**AVD Emulator**

- Target: Android 6.0
- API Level 23
- CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom
  (x86)
- Google account has been added to emulator

**Android SDK Packages**

- SDK Platform - Android 6.0 (API 23)
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Google APIs

**Android SDK Extras**

- Android Support Repository
- Google Play services
- Google Repository
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator

**Google Project**

- Google Cloud Messaging enabled
- Server API key credential created
- Project number noted

**Azure**

- Mobile App Service
- Notification Hub
- Notification Hub set to use GCM API Key

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("<MyAppServiceUrl>");
    var push = PushNotification.init({
            android: {
                senderID: "<MyGCMProjectNumber"
            }});

    push.on('registration', function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        client.push.register('gcm', data.registrationId);
    });

    push.on('notification', function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

The 'registration' handler gets called, returning an object with something like

```
{"registrationID":"dB2xexFY48E......."}
```

But that's where my success ends. No Registration Operation ever appears in the Azure portal, and test notifications sent from the portal are not received in the emulator.

Comment: Have you actually linked your Notification Hub to your Azure Mobile App?  Check to see if there is a connection string in your mobile apps Application Settings.

Comment: Yep, it's connected. I'm wondering now if it's an Android Emulator issue. When creating an AVD I was targeting Android 6.0 with Google APIs selected under CPU, because if I select Google APIs from the target dropdown, it says no system images are available. I just found this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210223

I think perhaps push notifications won't work unless I can target Google APIs.

Comment: That's the very next thing to check - you mentioned Google APIs - these are required in the system image - although you are getting a registration Id, so I'm not sure.  The next thing to try is to add a custom API that does the registration for you - check out my blog on the subject: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/23/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-24-push-with-tags/

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out! If I can't create an AVD with Google APIs, is there anywhere I could get a preconfigured one?

Comment: Would you say that successfully getting a registrationId means that the emulator and plugins are setup OK? In which case my problem is probably connecting to Azure?

Comment: YEs - if you get a registrationId from the PNS, then your emulator and phonegap-push-plugin are set up correctly.